# RAM capacity not displayed correctly in Windows

Tags: memory

I have an Acer desktop with an AMD Athlon processor and 1 GB RAM (DDR2). In addition I bought a 2 GB DIMM to upgrade it.  After adding it, I started my system and went into computer properties to check if the capacity changed.  However, it still remains as 1 GB.

Is there a way to fix the RAM?

Comment: Was the new ram DDR2 or any other type? Is it listed in BIOS screen? (Use `esc` or `del` or `f2` to access BIOS during startup.)

Comment: Also did you confirm that the board supports 2GB sticks(not just 2x1GB)?

Answer (score 0):

Reseat the RAM. Or even better, swap out the 1GB stick with the 2GB stick to see if the 2GB stick actually works. You'll need to provide more details on the model or motherboard model. Some old board had the ability to take DDR2 AND DDR3 or DDR AND DDR2. However, you can't use both types on the same board, as they are used for upgrade purposes.